# How to avoid the ServiceLocator anti-pattern?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, desktop-application, impersonation, service-locator

In order to access the underlying data source, I need to provide the current user credentials which I don't have beforehand.

So, in order to provide the data access layer with proper current user credentials, I have been suggested that my `ConfigurationProvider` would depend on an instance of `ICurrentUser` `InSingletonScope()` as per [**`this answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015976/162167).

The way I understand it, I shall make sure about authenticating the user, and bind my `ICurrentUser` afterwards, and binding the rest of my data access layer.

As the authentication occurs in my main MDI form, the only way I can see to achieve it, is to inject the Ninject kernel into the constructor of my MDI form.

My concern is about the fact that the way I see it, it would be necessary to depend on the Ninject kernel itself, which is absolutely out of the question, since this would then be, if I am not mistaken, just like using the `ServiceLocator` anti-pattern.

So, in this scenario, how to avoid the `ServiceLocator` anti-pattern?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021766/multitenancy-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-ninject-one-database-per-tenant, describes a bit the same problem. But I think you're missing the point. You don't need IKernel on your authentication form. Access `CurrentUser.Instance` as a singleton and don't reference the `ServiceLocator`. But now you are coupled to a `static`. :) But again, you can get around this implementing an `ICurrentUserAcessor` and masking the static access inside!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will,

You don't need to have access to `IResolutionRoot` in your authentication form. Having configured. I've came up with a sample implementation that uses an `IAuthenticationService` injected into your form. After user input you can call `SignIn()` and it will change the current credentials instance.

From that point on, every time a class that requires a `IDatabaseUserCredentials` will receive this instance instead of the default instance.

I've also made the `ConfigurationProvider` receive a `IConnectionStringProvider` instead of a `string`. Check the [complete gist](https://gist.github.com/cvbarros/04db931a2c257026aef1) for a full-working example.

```cs
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string dbInstance, string login, string password)
    {
        var user = new DatabaseUserCredentials(dbInstance, login, password);

        // A single point to manipulate your singleton instance
        DatabaseUserCredentials.Current = user;
    }
}
```

And the bindings:

```cs
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<Configuration>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>();

    Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<AuthenticationService>();

    Bind<IConnectionStringProvider>().To<ConnectionStringProvider>();

    //Use Current user if available. If not, use default credentials.
    Bind<IDatabaseUserCredentials>().ToMethod(c => DatabaseUserCredentials.Current ?? DatabaseUserCredentials.Default);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it makes sense at all, my friend (if I may say so)! I shall give it a try on the beginning of next week, I provide you feedback with your solution. Sincerely, pretty much thank you for your assistance. I really, and I mean really, appreciate it. Thanks a lot.